# html css arrow animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, tailwind-css

I have an arrow

->

I want to create this kind of animation

base ## hovered

-> #### >

The line goes to the right

The problem I got:

- When I hover over the icon the line(-) goes to the right but we still can see the line in the corner of the >-(here in the end) icon.

What I tried to do:
I have the code in tailwind css:

```
 <div className={"w-4 bg-red-300 h-[21px]"}>
    <div
      className={
        "flex items-center justify-end relative group cursor-pointer"
      }
    >
      <div
        className={
          "flex items-center h-full bg-yellow-300  h-[21px] overflow-hidden"
        }
      >
        <svg
          width="22"
          height="3"
          viewBox="0 0 22 3"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          className={"group-hover:translate-x-[100%] transition-all"}
        >
          <rect
            id="Rectangle 1"
            y="0.414215"
            width="22"
            height="2"
            fill="#C4C4C4"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>

      <svg
        width="12"
        height="21"
        viewBox="0 0 12 21"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        className={"absolute right-[-1px] top-0"}
      >
        <g id="Group 1">
          <rect
            id="Rectangle 2"
            x="0.464767"
            y="1.879"
            width="2"
            height="14.0706"
            transform="rotate(-45 0.464767 1.879)"
            fill="#C4C4C4"
          />
          <rect
            id="Rectangle 3"
            x="0.470001"
            y="18.9445"
            width="13.04"
            height="2"
            transform="rotate(-45 0.470001 18.9445)"
            fill="#C4C4C4"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I also wanted to decrease the width of the ling along with changing its origin to right, I did it with scale(n, 1) where n is 1 -> 0. 1 - full size, 0 - zero size.
It worked but I still could see a small piece of the line at the end of the > icon.

Maybe, someone knows a good approach for this kind of animation?